# Fire mouseenter even after close a modal dialog with the escape key

Tags: jquery

I need to invoke the execution of mouseenter when close a modal. I'm working with bootstrap and when the user closes the modal pressing the Escape key and the cursor is over an element is not executed hover event that I have implemented.
There a way to trigger an event mouseenter directly on these elements or globally to the browser.

I tried creating a new event as follows:

```
var e = $.Event('mouseenter');
e.pageX = 50;
e.pageY = 50;
$(".item").trigger(e);
```

But I failed to run depending on the mouse position and all elements running the event as having the mouse over.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way:

```
$(".item").on("mouseenter",function(){
   //do what you want
})

function onClose(){ //your function when the Escape key is pressed
  $(".item").trigger("mouseenter");
}
```

I also made [a small demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6KY9/5/)